# "/" redirect to php application home rather than host home

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lets say I have the following folder structure

```
/myprojects
    /app1
        index.php
        about.php
    /app2
```

I want to be able to make my links relative within the application

eg: if on a page within app1 I have:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

I want it to go to the 'app1' index page, not the 'myprojects' index page

Would I use .htaccess/mod_rewrite to do this?  Or something within php?

Comment: how is this going to work with app2, how to know which home to go to?

Comment: ``<a href="./">Home</a>``

Comment: If app1 and app2 independence, you can add virtual host to apache or simple goto app1 folder and run cmd "php -S localhost:8888"

Comment: @tim that would depend on the solution - eg: if .htaccess file, each app directory would have its own .htaccess file

Comment: @kmoser that doesn't seem to work.  What does ./ do?  I have seen ../ before, but not ./

Comment: @NguyênNgôDuy I feel like it should be simpler that this. I know it works somehow with CakePHP, just need to figure out how to get it to work on my mini frameworkless application...

Comment: ``./`` means "this folder". What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Where does ``./`` link to?